# How do I "dynamically" add css class?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

Inside my aspx file, I have the following html code inside an repeater: `<div class="someItem ">`.

Now, if `Eval("Approved") == true`, then I would like to add the class **approved** to the div. 
So the new html would be `<div class="someItem approved">`.

I tried doing something like this:

```
<%# if(Eval("Approved")) approved %>
```

But that didn't work very well. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If can't work in databinding # line.

So you can work around this by something like this:

```
<%# isApproved = Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("Approved").ToString()) %>
<% if(isApproved){ %>
  <div class="someItem approved">
<%}%>
```

And don't forget to declare `isApproved` as protected in the code behind.

Also please take a look at this question:

[Is it possible to use Data-Binding Expressions directly in markup to show/hide content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1553881/is-it-possible-to-use-data-binding-expressions-directly-in-markup-to-show-hide-co)

Which may answer the most important part of your question.

Comment: Hi Amr. Thanks for good answer. Your first line does not store the value in 'isApproved' variable. It just outputs the text "true" or "false". I was hoping to avoid code behind. But it looks like I have to call a function and pass the object Eval("approved").

Answer (score 2):

You can make the div a server control as -->

```
<div id="myDIV" class="myClass" runat="server"></div>.
```

Then you can directly access it from your code behind, as

```
myDIV.Attributes["class"] = "classOfYourChoice";
```

See this --> [How to edit CSS style of a div using C# in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/175381/how-to-edit-css-style-of-a-div-using-c-in-net)

Comment: Hum... I didn't know I could make html tags into a server control. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

maybe it would be better to consider this if the item is approved `<div id="someItem">` and then add class approved if the eval of whatever is true ..

```
<div id="someItem" "<%# Eval("Approved") ? Response.Write("class=\"approved\"") : "" %>">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an asp.net panel and control the action of it from the code behind. A panel renders as a DIV and you have access to it's CssClass during the runtime.